# Global Variable “total” Does Not Update Properly

Tags: haskell, global-variables

I'm working on an assignment to calculate the sum of all integers in a list. I am supposed to *do so without help from any standard library functions other than the standard addition operator*.

I assume this means I cannot use `length`. **I'm understanding that correct, right?** This becomes and issue as I'm not sure how I'd know when to stop my recursive function to iterate through the array.

The input's a should be expected to deal with are `[]` and `[0-X]` where x is any integer. The example has X as 10, so don't expect anything huge to be tested.

The assignment mentioned it should be in the following format, but I'm not sure I follow:

```
sum1 []     = ...
sum1 (x:xs) = ...
```

Here's what I have utilizing length. It works correctly, and I don't really care if it's inefficient. It's my first time using Haskell:

```
iterate_list :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> IO()
iterate_list func_list index total = do
    if index < length func_list
    then do
        let new_total = total + (func_list !! index)
        let new_index = index + 1
        iterate_list func_list new_index new_total
    else 
        print(total)
        

sum1 :: [Int] -> IO()
sum1 list = do
    if length list < 1
    then do
        print(0)
    else
        iterate_list list 0 0
```

---

*update:* Based on comments, here is the code I've produced.

```
total :: Int
total = 0

sum1 :: [Int] -> IO()
sum1 (x:xs) = do
    if xs == []
    then do
        print(total)
    else do
        let total = total + x
        sum1 xs
```

However, the issue I'm having now is `total` returns 0, almost like it's a constant. I might be programming it that way, but I'm not too sure what's going on.

Based on the assignment description, I **cannot** pass a variable through the recursive function to store this value. I've done it that way before. Does anyone know if there is a way to have a "`total`" variable outside of the function.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly compute the length of the list to compute the sum of all its elements. Your assignment gives you a big hint; your code does not follow that hint. Write down the code in the hint and fill in the parts which are `...`.

Comment: I.e., what is the sum of an empty list? What's the sum of a non-empty list, given that you have the ability to compute the sum of the list `xs` before performing an addition?

Comment: Compared to other languages, in Haskell indexes are not use that much. You should think in terms of recursion: what is the sum of an empty list? What is the sum of a non-empty list if you have the sum of the tail of that list?

Comment: I would think that `(<)` and `(!!)` also count as standard library functions to be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone. I've come across a different issue. Hopefully you're able to help me out. Updating in the next couple minutes

Comment: You are still thinking far too imperatively. Again, what should `sum []` return? Once you have that, you can simply add `x` to whatever `sum xs` returns in the recursive case.

Comment: Your type should just be `sum1 :: [Int] -> Int`; your function has no business printing anything. If the caller wants to print the sum, they can do so after `sum1` has returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
total :: Int
total = 0

sum1 :: [Int] -> IO()
sum1 (x:xs) = do
    if xs == []
    then do
        print(total)
    else do
        let total = total + x
        sum1 xs
```

What this code says:

- The global `total` is a *constant* integer, equal to `0`
- `sum1` takes a list of integers and produces an IO action that produces no result
- If `sum1` is given a non-empty list, then:

  - If the tail of that list is empty (i.e., the whole list has 1 element), then print the global variable `total`
  - Otherwise:

    - Create a *new local variable* named `total`, hiding the global one, and define it as `x` plus itself (an infinite loop)
    - Recursively call `sum1` on the tail of the list
- If `sum1` is given an empty list, it will throw an error

This shows that you’re thinking very imperatively. Rather than trying to define a bottom-up *procedure* for updating the total incrementally until it *builds up* to the final result, you need to think in terms of how to compute the total as a value by *breaking down* the input. Variables in Haskell are *immutable*; when you write `=`, it means *equal*, never “assign” or “update”.

First, `sum1` should return `Int` because you don’t need `IO` or `do` notation for this.

```
sum1 :: [Int] -> Int
```

If you want to print the result of `sum1` applied to some list `someList` (for example from `main`), use `print` there, i.e., `print (sum1 someList)`.

Next, the function should be defined in terms of the the two possible cases of the input: an empty list and a non-empty list.

```
sum1 [] = …

sum1 (x : xs) = …
```

You need to define these cases so that an input like `sum1 [1, 2, 3, 4]`, which you’ll recall is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `sum1 (1 : (2 : (3 : (4 : []))))` produces something equivalent to `1 + 2 + 3 + 4`.

First, in the case of an empty list, what should the result be? You can deduce this from the fact that the sum of two lists appended together should be the same as the sum of each of them separately; that is, for any lists `xs` and `ys`, these expressions should produce the same result:

```
sum1 xs + sum1 ys
sum1 (xs ++ ys)
```

Supposing `xs` or `ys` is empty, it should not change the sum:

- `sum1 [] + sum1 ys` = `sum1 ([] ++ ys)` = `sum1 ys`
- `sum1 xs + sum1 []` = `sum1 (xs ++ [])` = `sum1 xs`

Second, as for the non-empty case: you’re given an element `x :: Int` and a list `xs :: [Int]`, and you need to compute the total of the two. For example, given `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `x` is set to `1` and `xs` is `[2, 3, 4]`. Suppose you had the sum of `xs` already; what is the result in terms of that and `x`? And how can you obtain the sum of `xs`?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Haskell is a little foreign to me... This really helped with my understanding

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* simply update a variable in Haskell. All values are immutable. You should be thinking in terms of how to use the return value of a recursive call, not simply calling a function for its side effect.

The hint from your original question was to define

```
sum [] = ...
sum (x:xs) = ...
```

First, what is the sum of the non-empty list? It must include `x`, so you'll be adding something to `x`:

```
sum (x:xs) = x + ...
```

Second, what is the sum of an empty list? While it might not make sense to even *define* a value for an empty list, think about what `sum [3]` must surely return, and the fact that `sum (3:[]) == 3 + ...`. There's a rather simple definition for `sum []` that is almost dictated by the definition of addition.

Comment: Thanks for helping me in the comments. Helped me get on the right track. This answer is helpful too. Thanks!